# What's wrong here? Zend FW getDependentRowSet()

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, zend-db

Trying to use the getDependentRowset in a ZF application. I have the following relationship between two tables:

[image]

Where a user's organisation is a FK of the organisation table's PK, organisationId.

What I want to do is, retrieve a users' organisation name (`organisation.name`) by the user Id (`user.userId`).

Here's my User db-table model:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

        protected $_name = 'user';

        //define foreign keys here
        protected $_referenceMap = array (
            'Organisation'=> array (
            'columns'=>'organisation_organisationId',
            'refTableClass'=>'Organisation',
            'refColumns'=>'organisationId'
            )
        );

        public function getUser($emailAddress, $password) {

            $select = $this->select()
                            ->where("emailAddress = \"$emailAddress\" AND password=\"$password\"", 1);
            $row = $this->fetchRow($select);
            return $row;

        }

    }
```

And the offending code in my IndexController:

```
$user = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
$res = $user->getUser($emailAddress, $password);
$organisationInfo = $res->findDependentRowset('organisation');
```

And ideas what could be causing this? I know this is relatively simple stuff!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I belive an *organization* table is a parent table to the *user* table. So you should be using `$res->findParentRow('Application_Model_DbTable_Organization');`. However, when you want to find all users in a given organization, than you would use `getDependentRowSet()` method of an *organisation* row object.

Comment: That's solved it! Thanks very much! Also needed to change refTableClass to 'refTableClass'=>'Application_Model_DbTable_Organisation' in the User model.